# how to make gameobject jump forward?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

hi i'm really new to this and would like some help, i would like to know how i can make my game object jump forward (the longer you hold the further it'll jump), i have a rigid body on my game object already in case that helps.

```
public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed;

private Vector3 dir;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    dir = Vector3.zero;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
    {
        if (dir == Vector3.forward)
        {
            dir = Vector3.right;
        }
        else 
        {
            dir = Vector3.forward;
        }

    }

    float AmToMove = speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.Translate (dir * AmToMove);
}
```

so far i only managed to make it move forward and right but instead i would like it to jump forward and jump right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public float thrust;
        public Rigidbody rb;
        void Start() {
            rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        }
        void FixedUpdate() {
            rb.AddForce(transform.up * thrust);
        }
//This will add a force to the rigidbody upwards.
```

If you want to use the rigidbody for movement you should apply a force to it. Right now you are simply moving the world transform of the object.